# Regex how to escape double quotes if needed

Tags: php, regex

I need to convert all big integers to strings in my response json. Currently my regex look like this

```
preg_replace(
            '/:\s*(-?\d{16,})/',
            ': "$1"',
            $content
        );
```

But problem with such regex is that if my response contains another json string then bigints inside it will be wrapped in string too, but without escaping. Is there any way to escape appended quotes in such case? Or maybe fix incorrect json with another regex?

Example

```
{"example_bigint": 3330922503411457761} 

will be converted to

{"example_bigint": "3330922503411457761"} 

but

{"example_json" : "{\"example_bigint\": 3330922503411457761}"} 

will be converted to 

{"example_json" : "{\"example_bigint\": "3330922503411457761"}"} 

when expected output is

{"example_json" : "{\"example_bigint\": \"3330922503411457761\"}"}
```

Comment: Try `preg_replace('~((?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\{2})*\K\\\\)?"\s*:\s*\K-?\d{16,}~', ': $1"$0"$1', $content)` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/VGmyH2/1)).

Comment: You have a very strange JSON...

Comment: Алексей, please check the answer below and let know if that works for you by either accepting that answer (if yes), or provide more feedback (if no).

Answer (score 1):

There is a flag in the json_decode function:

```php
$myJson = json_decode($jsonString, flags: JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
```